# How to select specific items in IN sql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "products" with a column called "store_id".
This table has a lot af products from many stores.
I need to select 4 random products from 4 specific stores (id: 1, 34, 45, 100).
How can I do that?

I've tried to like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE store_id IN (1, 34, 45, 100)
```

But that query returns duplicated records (by store_id).
I need the following result:

| store_id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title a |
| 34 | title b |
| 45 | title c |
| 100 | title d |

Comment: "*4 ramdom products*" - how random does it need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT construct to get unique records for the desired column:

```
SELECT distinct on (store_id) store_id, title FROM products WHERE store_id IN (1, 34, 45, 100);
```

Demo in [sqldaddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/b36009c8)

Comment: That won't be random though

Answer (score 2):

To get a true random pick of the products use a `row_number` function with *random order*.

This query shows all data with a random index of the product for each store

```
select products.*,
row_number() over (partition by store_id order by random()) rn
from products
where store_id in (1,34)

store_id|product_id|title|rn|
--------+----------+-----+--+
       1|         1|a    | 1|
       1|         3|c    | 2|
       1|         2|b    | 3|
      34|         6|f    | 1|
      34|         7|g    | 2|
      34|         8|h    | 3|
      34|         5|e    | 4|
      34|         4|d    | 5|
```

To get only one product per store simple filter with `rn=1`

```
with prod as (
select products.*,
row_number() over (partition by store_id order by random()) rn
from products
where store_id in (1,34)
)
select store_id, title from prod
where rn = 1
;

store_id|title|
--------+-----+
       1|a    |
      34|e    |
```

Note this query will produce a different result on each run. If you need a stability you must call [setseed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) before each execution. E.g.

```
SELECT setseed(1)
```