# Sorting Varchar version in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table packages with column version(Varchar) and I cannot sort string literals just like that.

So is there any way I can get the latest package version?

Data is in this format :

```
id | version
128,3.0.5-1
128,3.0.6-1
128,3.0.7-1
128,3.0.8-1
128,3.0.9-1
128,3.0.13-2
128,3.0.4-1-1
128,3.0.10-1
128,3.0.11-2
128,3.0.11-1
```

I came to a solution something like:

```
SELECT  version
FROM packages
ORDER BY
    -- First, sort by the first number in the version
    SUBSTRING(version, '^[0-9]+') DESC,
    -- Then, sort by the second number in the version
    SUBSTRING(version, '[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+)-') DESC,
    -- Then, sort by the third number in the version
    CAST(SUBSTRING(version, '[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+-([0-9]+)') AS INTEGER) DESC,
    -- Finally, sort by the fourth number in the version
    SUBSTRING(version, '[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+)') DESC
    -- Return only the first row
```

This returns :

```
3.0.5-1
3.0.6-1
3.0.7-1
3.0.8-1
3.0.9-1
3.0.13-2
3.0.4-1-1
3.0.10-1
3.0.11-2
3.0.11-1
```

It seems that this works fine until 3.0.10-1 so the problem is it follows x.x.x-x pattern but does not work when the x is two digits.

Is there any way I can achieve this within query itself?
I would really appreciate if someone can give me hint or a solution.

Edit: Accepted answer is correct and its working, but now I have case where version comes with release and it can be string so query fails for this data:

```
id | version
128,3.0.5-1-test-dev
128,3.0.6-1
128,3.0.7-1-test
128,3.0.8-1-test-dev-test23
128,3.0.9-1
128,3.0.13-2
128,3.0.4-1-1
128,3.0.10-1
128,3.0.11-2
128,3.0.11-1
```

Comment: Normalisation is key here; if each part of your version number carries specific meaning it belongs in its own numeric column - then your issue disappears.

Comment: Yeah that would be great, but I cannot change the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split_part()` is better suited for this kind of splitting a string into elements.

You also need to convert each element to a number to get a correct sorting:

```
select *
from packages
order by split_part(version, '.', 1)::int,
         split_part(version, '.', 2)::int,
         string_to_array(split_part(version, '.', 3), '-')::int[]
```

The third part (e.g. `11-1'`) is converted to an integer array which can be sorted directly.

If you **only** had versions like `3.0.5` this could be sorted by converting the whole version number into an integer array. You can achieve this by replacing the minus sign with a dot:

```
select *
from packages
order by string_to_array(replace(version, '-', '.'), '.')::int[];
```

And to only get the latest package version:

```
select *
from packages
order by string_to_array(replace(version, '-', '.'), '.')::int[] desc
fetch first row only;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/mBw2-OQC

Comment: This works just perfectly! Thank you.
In addition to this, now if I have sorted versions for different IDs, is there any way I can take distinct IDs with top versions? I cannot use SELECT distinct on (id) and this ORDER BY function?
Data is like this: 
`127,3.0.5-1
127,3.0.6-1
127,3.0.7-1
127,3.0.7-2
112,3.0.10-1
118,3.0.10-1
109,3.0.10-1
104,3.0.11-1
111,3.0.11-1
105,3.0.11-1
127,3.1.7-1
127,3.1.9-1
117,21.9.0-2
`

Comment: @Nicola - use `row_number` where you can define the order explicitely. Similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74657214/4808122).

Comment: The `string_to_array` sort is a superb solution that work even in case the version consist of variable number of parts. In such case the `split_part` can fail the cast to `int`  with `invalid input syntax for type integer: ""`, so `nullif(split_part(version, '.', 4),'')::int`  is more safe.

Comment: what about case when I have some version with text like: version: 1-sometext. Is there way to include this case into query? Because that few rows now are problem that left with text